# Getting NA irrespective of the factor conversion method used

Tags: r, dataframe

I see this question has been asked a lot of times and I myself have tried all the methods to convert my factors to numeric including:

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))

lapply(x, function(y) as.numeric(levels(y))[y])

as.numeric.factor <- function(y) as.numeric(levels(y))[y]
lapply(x, as.numeric.factor)
```

I cannot use the `unlist` function because I want the output in the wide format and `unlist` converts it to long.

But all of them are giving NA values as output.

When I specifically check x, it shows the values appropriately.

```
> class(x)
[1] "data.frame"

> class(x$Col2)
[1] "factor"

> class(x$Col1)
[1] "Date"
```

Please find a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(354)
df <- data.frame(Product_Id = rep(1:100, each = 50), 
                 Date = seq(from = as.Date("2014/1/1"), to = as.Date("2018/2/1") , by = "month"), 
                 Sales = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd= 20))
df <- df[-c(251:256, 301:312, 2551:2562, 2651:2662, 2751:2762), ]

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(df, index = "Date", split = "Product_Id", FUN = as.yearmon)
tt <- as.ts(z)

fcast <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(tt), nrow = 12)

library(forecast)
for(i in 1:ncol(tt)){
  fc1 <- forecast(stlf(na.trim(tt[,i]),h=12))
  fcast[,i] <-fc1$mean
}

forecasted <- format(round(rbind(tt, fcast),2),nsmall = 2)
dd <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), by = 'months', length = nrow(forecasted)),Prod_Id = forecasted)
dd_f <- lapply(dd, function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
```

Any suggestion as to what can I be missing?

Comment: you're missing a representative example...

Comment: Could you add your data?

Comment: Also, first `x` then `dd`. Can you be more clear?

Comment: `x <- data.frame(Col2 = c("1.23", "2.34"));y <- lapply(x, as.numeric.factor);str(y)` gives me the right numbers, not `NA`

Comment: Hey, added an example. In my actual code, I am also performing a forecast on tt and the forecasted dataframe is then converted to numeric. But, in this case also, I am getting the same error. Should the values be converted to numeric in some other way?

Comment: there is no factor in your data... (and your `tt` data are already numeric)

Comment: Hey, as mentioned earlier, I was performing forecast on the data. I have added that part to the code as well. Now `class(dd$Prod_Id.1)
[1] "factor"`.

Comment: passing your code, I get numeric values as expected. You shouldn't apply it on the first col though, as it is a date

Comment: You mean `dd_f <- lapply(dd[,c(2:ncol(dd))], function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])`